# make: *** No rule to make target '-', needed by 'TTCN3_DIR'. Stop

Tags: installation, makefile, gnu-make, titan, ttcn

I am trying to install the Titan by creating the **Makefile** with name **Makefile.personal** into the titan.core folder under the home directory of **cygwin**. But unfortunately, I am facing the below issue while giving this command **make -j5**.

```
Makefile.personal

TTCN3_DIR :- D:/cygwin64/home/SUBBARAM/install
OPENSSL_DIR :- /usr
JDKDIR :- /etc/java-config-2/current-system-vm
XMLDIR :- /usr
JNI :- yes
GEN_PDF :- no
~
```

Below is the Error,

```
$ make -j5
make: *** No rule to make target '-', needed by 'TTCN3_DIR'.  Stop.
```

I'd appreciate help in understanding the cause of and solution to this error. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure where `:-` came from.  That's not a valid make operator.  I assume you really meant `:=` here.

Comment: Thanks MadScientist, it solved the problem.
But I have an issue with compilation and asked the question in the given link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634270/getting-error-while-installing-titan-core