# Getting Error while installing titan.core

Tags: titan, ttcn

While installing the Titan (Repository taken form the site https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipse/titan/titan.core), getting the error as below

Solved the **Makefile** issue in my previous question([make: *** No rule to make target '-', needed by 'TTCN3_DIR'. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77629974/make-no-rule-to-make-target-needed-by-ttcn3-dir-stop)), Thanks @user:939557

Error Details:

```
$ make -j
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/common'
openssl_version.c:14:10: fatal error: openssl/crypto.h: No such file or directory
   14 | #include <openssl/crypto.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [../Makefile.genrules:90: openssl_version.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  (C++)  pattern_la.cc
  (C++)  pattern_p.cc
pattern_p.y:976:6: warning: ‘void yyprint(FILE*, int, const YYSTYPE&)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
  976 | void yyprint(FILE *file, int type, const YYSTYPE& value)
      |      ^~~~~~~
NetworkHandler.cc: In function ‘virtual int IPv4Address::accept(int)’:
NetworkHandler.cc:210:12: warning: ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’ specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]
  210 |     strncpy(m_addr_str, inet_ntoa(m_addr.sin_addr), sizeof(m_addr_str));
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
NetworkHandler.cc:216:16: warning: ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’ specified bound 1025 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]
  216 |         strncpy(m_host_str, hptr->h_name, sizeof(m_host_str));
      |         ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
NetworkHandler.cc: In member function ‘virtual bool IPv6Address::set_addr(const char*, short unsigned int)’:
NetworkHandler.cc:336:12: warning: ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’ specified bound 1025 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]
  336 |     strncpy(m_host_str, res->ai_canonname, sizeof(m_host_str));
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In member function ‘virtual bool IPv4Address::set_addr(const char*, short unsigned int)’,
    inlined from ‘virtual bool IPv4Address::set_addr(const char*, short unsigned int)’ at NetworkHandler.cc:186:6:
NetworkHandler.cc:196:14: warning: ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’ specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]
  196 |       strncpy(m_addr_str, inet_ntoa(m_addr.sin_addr), sizeof(m_addr_str));
      |       ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
NetworkHandler.cc:197:14: warning: ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’ specified bound 1025 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]
  197 |       strncpy(m_host_str, hptr->h_name, sizeof(m_host_str));
      |       ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/common'
make: *** [Makefile:65: all] Error 2
```

I'd appreciate help in understanding the cause of and solution to this error. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have openssl installed. See my other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77654173/error-while-installing-titan-core-in-cygwin/77660243