# Error while installing titan.core in cygwin

Tags: installation, makefile, titan, ttcn

While installing the Titan (Repository taken form the site https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipse/titan/titan.core), and create a **Makefile** as below snippet getting the error as below

Makefile

```
TTCN3_DIR:=  D:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install
OPENSSL_DIR := /usr
JDKDIR :=  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21
XMLDIR := /usr
JNI := yes
GEN_PDF := no
```

Error:

```
SUBBARAMAIAH@SUBBARAMAIAH ~/titan.core
$ make -j
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/common'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/common'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2'
make -C asn1
make -C ttcn3
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2/asn1'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2/ttcn3'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2/asn1'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2/ttcn3'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/repgen'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/repgen'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/xsdconvert'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/xsdconvert'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/mctr2'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/mctr2/cli'
  (C++)  Cli.cc
Cli.cc:45:10: fatal error: editline/readline.h: No such file or directory
   45 | #include <editline/readline.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [../../Makefile.genrules:97: Cli.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/mctr2/cli'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:32: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/mctr2'
make: *** [Makefile:65: all] Error 2
```

Also, getting Error while clean the compiled files as below:

```
$ make clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/common'
rm -f  memory.o new.o userinfo.o path.o config_preproc.o Quadruple.o Path2.o ModuleVersion.o JSON_Tokenizer.o UnicharPattern.o openssl_version.o NetworkHandler.o pattern_la.o pattern_p.o pattern_uni.o config_preproc_la.o config_preproc_p.tab.o git_version.o git_version.c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/common'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2/asn1'
rm -f libasn1_compiler.a AST_asn1.o Ref.o Block.o Object.o OCSV.o Tag.o TableConstraint.o TokenBuf.o Type_parse.o asn1la.yy.o asn1p.tab.o asn1_preparser.lex.o
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2/asn1'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2/ttcn3'
rm -f libttcn3_compiler.a ArrayDimensions.o AST_ttcn3.o Attributes.o ILT.o PatternString.o RawAST.o Statement.o TtcnTemplate.o Templatestuff.o TextAST.o Ttcnstuff.o compiler.o port.o signature.o BerAST.o JsonAST.o Ttcn2Json.o profiler.o OerAST.o PerAST.o lex.ttcn3.o compiler.tab.o lex.rawAST.o rawAST.tab.o charstring_la.o pstring_la.o comptype_attrib_la.o coding_attrib_la.o coding_attrib_p.o ttcn3_preparser.lex.o ../../common/JSON_Tokenizer.o
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2/ttcn3'
rm -f compiler.exe ttcn3_makefilegen.exe tcov2lcov.exe encdec.o enum.o functionref.o record.o record_of.o union.o PredefFunc.o AST.o Code.o Constraint.o CompilerError.o CompField.o CompType.o EnumItem.o Identifier.o Int.o main.o Real.o Setting.o SigParam.o string.o subtype.o Stopwatch.o Type.o Type_chk.o Type_codegen.o TypeCompat.o Typestuff.o ustring.o Value.o Valuestuff.o XerAttributes.o subtypestuff.o CodeGenHelper.o DebuggerStuff.o XSD_Types.o makefile.o xpather.o ProjectGenHelper.o tcov2lcov.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/compiler2'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core'
make[1]: *** repgen: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core'
make: *** [Makefile:65: clean] Error 2
```

I'd appreciate help in understanding the cause of and solution to this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You either don't have `libreadline-devel` installed or it is installed in a folder that is not in your include path.

If it is simply not installed, just install this package.

In the latter case, add the correct path to CPPFLAGS in `Makefile.personal` that is the preferred Makefile for titan to set your own changes. Probably the library path is also needed:

`CPPFLAGS := -I/path/to/libreadline/include -L/path/to/libreadline/lib`

Also check your libedit version. If it is 0.53.0 or older, you also need this:

`OLD_LIBEDIT := yes`

otherwise your build will fail.

Make sure to install all other deps listed here:

[Titan install guide](https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipse/titan/titan.core/-/blob/master/usrguide/installationguide/installationguide.adoc?ref_type=heads) section 1.5, paragraph 8/c (don't forget to install all the other packages from paragraph a and b as well).

Comment: I tried with the above process by checking and installed the ** libreadline-devel** and also add the CPPFLAGS := -I C:\cygwin64\usr\include -L C:\cygwin64\lib
, OLD_LIBEDIT := yes, but still getting the same error as below
*Cli.cc:45:10: fatal error: editline/readline.h: No such file or directory
   45 | #include <editline/readline.h>*

Comment: Well, it seems README.cygwin in the root dir of the source has a more up to date dependency list. I guess you miss `libedit-devel`.